# CSS display-table width 100% - missing pixel?

Tags: html, css

I have a few div containers with overlays inside of them:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I set overlay display to table (it has to be table as I'm centering stuff both vertically & horizontally there - just simplified this example for SO) like so:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fed900;
    outline: solid 5px #000;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: table;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I'm getting weird glitch - although developer tools tell me the overlay has the same width as container - in some cases the overlay width equals container's width minus 1 pixel. Why? What am I missing? And how to fix that? :)

[image: overlay]

http://jsfiddle.net/v13mdq57/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the width, the calculation is giving you a half pixel (which can't be rendered). We can achieve this without `display: table`. I'm not quite sure why this only occurs with `display: table`, but leaving the overlay as a block element fixes the problem.

In this example:

- `.overlay:before` brings inline elements into the middle. It is an invisible element that is lined up on the left hand side *inside* the overlay.
- The closing and opening div tags have no white space between them, which prevents the inline gap.

[Read more about removing the gap between inline elements.](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
body { 
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fed900;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
}
.overlay:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">Centered</div>
</div><div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">Centered</div>
</div><div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">Centered</div>
</div><div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">Centered</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Calculation of width of what? How can 100% of 25% contain half-pixels? I don't like the pseudoelements too much, but will see :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is wrong with pseudo elements... Browser compatibility?

Comment: The half pixels happen because at some widths it will be calculated at something like 11.5px, which can't exist.

Answer (score -4):

```
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fed900;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: -3px;
}
```

Comment: Why -3px? Where's my 1 pixel from overlay gone? :)

Comment: your post need explanation. please provide some explanations