# display:table div with percentage width 1px bug

Tags: html, css, css-tables

The outer `div` have percentage width, and inner `div`'s have `display: tabel; width: 100%`.

The inner `div`'s show 1px less than outer `div` for some page widths while resizing. This adds an 1px line to the right.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/utcswLp1/1/

Is there any fix for the bug?

Comment: I am checking in chrome latest version. This happens for some browser widths only.

Comment: The same question has been asked many times and you can find the answer if you just google it. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204771/css-display-table-width-100-missing-pixel

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to be a specific webkit bug : https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140371

The width of a `display:table-*` element is not always properly calculated when contained in a parent whose `width` is not defined with an absolute unit. You can see this issue in action here: Look at the right side of red elements

[image]

---

You can fix this issue in 2 different ways

1. You could define the width of parent element with an absolute unit or
2. You could apply `display: table` also to the container element. This doesn't really solve the bug but it should not be noticeable anymore (because it will affect also the parent element).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem arises from the "60%" width of the container.

Chrome truncates decimals (300.5px will become 300px).
Therefore, when the inner `div` is set to "100%", it is calculated at the rounded width of the parent `div`

So, let's say that the outer div is 300.5px (60% of total).
The inner div is calulculated as 100% of 300px;

Comment: Why it happens only for `display: table`, and not for `display:block`?

Comment: Because `display:block` will take up the entire space. It doesn't matter what the `width` is. Therefore, it is not calculated. And thus, not rounded.

Answer (score 3):

```
.wrap{
background: #000; 
height: 400px;
width: 60%;
display:inline-table;}
```

Just change your css code like this

Answer (score 3):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    width: calc(100% + 0.5px);
}
```

Notes:

- adding 1px doesn't fix the problem on WebKit … it just inverts it
- adding 0.5px introduces the problem on some non-WebKit browsers … wrapping it in a media query resolves this

Answer (score 1):

Change your `display:table` to `display:block`.

Comment: I am  searching for a solution for this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather late, but here's a fix for this bug i had to deal with too.

As mentioned in this thread the problem lies in the usage of percentage as a unit of width. The browser rounds the decimals down to a full number. So all we need to do is add 1 Pixel to the percentage based with. We can do that with calc:

```
width: calc(100% + 1px);
```

This will work in all major browsers exept IE 11 and older.

Comment: Note that `calc` does work on IE 11 for this use case (IE 11 has other issues with `calc`, but not in conjunction with width): https://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 0):

The use of `display: table` can come with the unwanted side effect that table css styles are applied on the div. Therefore I chose `display: contents` for my project.