# 100% width Table & Div not exactly the same size

Tags: html, css

I have a Div and a Table in a container. They are both supposed to fill up the container completely but sometimes there is a one pixel difference which is very frustrating. I have recreated a test case and attached a screenshot where the bug is clearly visible (on the right side). Is there anyway to fix that ?

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.head {
  width: 100%;
  background: teal;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
      Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: works fine in the snippet

Comment: @dippas: In the small inline view, yes – but in Full Page view I can confirm the effect, it appears and disappears as I slowly resize the browser window width. (Browser: Vivaldi, so essentially same as Chrome.)

Comment: Check this question also - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719624/displaytable-div-with-percentage-width-1px-bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719624/displaytable-div-with-percentage-width-1px-bug)

Comment: It looks fine in my browser. However, is there a reason you can't put the teal background color on the container div instead of the head and table divs?

Comment: afelixj putting my head in display table worked

Comment: Is the problem still there if you set all the widths to be a fixed number of pixels instead of 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table width: 100% has a width which is rounded when 100% equals to something like 450.5 pixels while the div just take the full size no matter what without rounding so just putting : display: table on the div fixed the problem.