# Table 100% is less wide than siblbing div

Tags: css, google-chrome

So only in Chrome (Tested in 84.0.4147.105 Ubuntu and 87.0.4280.66 Windows 10), I can't make a table with 100% use the same width as a div. In this jsfiddle, they are one under the other, you can easily see that the green part (table with style width 100%) is not as wide as a div in the same context. The table is shorter by 0.5px to 1px.

[image]

Note: I noticed that at different zoom levels, it will sometime line up in Chrome, and sometime not, so if you see it lining up, zoom in/out.

In firefox, things line up no matter the zoom. Is there a CSS detail I didn't think to tweak that would solve this or is it a bug in Chrome? Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/HellzStormer/7nbuqop5/15/

Code from the jsfiddle:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="upper-div">
    Some text
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Other text </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* With or without changes nothing */
}
.wrap { width: 90px; }
.upper-div { background: red; }
table {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: This is a Webkit bug. Happens sometimes with Border as well. This will help you out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719624/displaytable-div-with-percentage-width-1px-bug

Webkit Bug link: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140371

Comment: @Karthik The link and bug mention a parent that is using a non static width. In this case, the parent is 90px, so i'm not sure it applies?

Comment: I think this applies here as well as I believe it is mostly due to rendering engine of the browser. I am facing this issue since past 4 years on my current project in chrome only. This happens at a different zoom levels between the header and body content. Ii see a black line coming between the header and body at a 140 zoom. If I change the background color the line color changes accordingly. I am not using tables just two divs siblings of each other. I am also and accessibility expert in my project, hence I have to experiment a lot with zoom of the webpages.

Answer (score -1):

Adding *display: block;* to *table* will do the trick.

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Doing so breaks the content of the table. The td doesn't use the whole width anymore.

Comment: The td never uses the whole width, if it’s content is smaller than the table’s width, unless you give it a width in pixels via CSS.

[TD width](http://torsten.bplaced.net/stackoverflow/div-table.png)

Comment: If I inspect the td in my example, I can clearly see it being 86px (4 less than the table, because the example doesn't have border-collapse). I would guess your screenshot was done after you applied your fix.

Comment: Yes, the screenshot was made after my fix.

Comment: You can only make the td as wide as the table, if you tell it to have the same width as the table in pixels (but not percent):

`td { width: 90px; }`

But what should be the use of this?

Comment: This was a minimal example showing a problem I had. My real use case had multiple cells and rows, but including all of it would have made the problem less obvious. I'm using a table because I need the table's behavior. Thanks anyways