# Display table-cell vertical-align middle create 1px weird spacing in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, css-tables

I need to centre my content in the div, so I use the table-cell and vertical-align to achieve it. However, it create a weird spacing like 1px in Chrome only. I can't really find the solution. Please do help me.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}
.img-wrapper, .txt-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.img-wrapper {
  background: yellow;
}
.txt-wrapper {
  background: green;
  display: table;
}
.txt {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.col1 {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  background: yellow;
  width: 50%;
}
.col2 {
  background: green;
  width: 50%;
}
.pushtoright {
  left: 50%;
}
.pulltoleft {
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="therow">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-wrapper">
    <div class="txt">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>Description 1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="therow">
  <div class="img-wrapper pushtoright">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-wrapper pulltoleft">
    <div class="txt">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>Description 2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="therow">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-wrapper">
    <div class="txt">
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>Description 3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="therow">
  <div class="img-wrapper pushtoright">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-wrapper pulltoleft">
    <div class="txt">
      <h2>Title 4</h2>
      <p>Description 4 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The demo : https://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/jwxJqX

Comment: Where do you see the space? Chrome 59.0.3071.115 on Mac, can't see any kind of weird spaces.

Comment: mine is mac chrome too: Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit). maybe can try to resize the window? then will see the red 1px line

Comment: When you use the Chrome developer tools and go to the 'computed' tab on the right, you'll see that the left div is 531px wide and the right one 531.5. There seems to be half a pixel lost in space.

Comment: @Gerard yeah, I realised it too. But I applied 50% width for each column. How can I solve it? It seems annoying.

Comment: Possible fix here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204771/css-display-table-width-100-missing-pixel

Comment: @Gerard It's not really working for copy more than 1 line. anyway thanks

Comment: Might even be related to the codepen interface, I played around a bit and came up with: https://codepen.io/webandapp/pen/vZrOjL ?

Comment: @axel.michel hi, i have tried it, but it's still there. i think you have missed out the 1px weird space, it go to the front instead of in between columns. not really related to codepen interface, but actually chrome's bug on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can do without **display: table** in **.txt-wrapper** , if this is not a problem for other things ... the strange effect disappears

```css
body {
  background: red;
}
.img-wrapper, .txt-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.img-wrapper {
  background: yellow;
}
.txt-wrapper {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;

  /*display: table;*/
}
.txt {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.col1 {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  background: yellow;
  width: 50%;
}
.col2 {
  background: green;
  width: 50%;
}
.pushtoright {
  left: 50%;
}
.pulltoleft {
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="therow">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-wrapper">
    <div class="txt">
      <h2>Title 1</h2>
      <p>Description 1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="therow">
  <div class="img-wrapper pushtoright">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-wrapper pulltoleft">
    <div class="txt">
      <h2>Title 2</h2>
      <p>Description 2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="therow">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-wrapper">
    <div class="txt">
      <h2>Title 3</h2>
      <p>Description 3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="therow">
  <div class="img-wrapper pushtoright">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="txt-wrapper pulltoleft">
    <div class="txt">
      <h2>Title 4</h2>
      <p>Description 4 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to make the words at the middle/centre of box. It's there any way to solve this? without creating the weird 1px?

Comment: I have edited mi answer. To center vertical and horizontal

Comment: If you want also <h2> to be centered you can use text-align:center for h2 or for entire .txt class to center all